# How to cancel an execution of a command window in C#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, command-line, backgroundworker, cancel-button

So I'm using visual studio to run a command line to get a `"dir /s >`

> c:\log.txt".

```
System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
startInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
startInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
startInfo.Arguments = "/C dir " + drivePath + " /s > c:\\log.txt";
process.StartInfo = startInfo;
process.Start();
process.WaitForExit();
```

I'm wanting to put this in a backgroundWorker so that I'm able to cancel it if the process is taking too long. But I don't see any way to cancel the execution of command line since the execution of the command is outside the scope of the program. Is there some logic I can add to this so that it will at least act as if I've cancelled it?

Comment: you may wait for timeout `process.WaitForExit(desiredTimeOut)`

Comment: Recursively listing files using the IO namespace then writing them to disk is trivial.  Process has a Kill() method.

Comment: WaitForExit has an overload to which you can pass a timeout. If the process does not exit in that duration, the method will return false. bool Process.WaitForExit(int)